# Can one collect with respect to two groups of variables?

Tags: polynomials, expression-manipulation, refactoring

Here is a toy example of what I want: given

```
 x[3,2] x[4,1] y[1,4] y[2,3]-x[3,1] x[4,2] y[1,4] y[2,3]
-x[3,2] x[4,1] y[1,3] y[2,4]+x[3,1] x[4,2] y[1,3] y[2,4]
+x[1,3] x[4,2] y[2,4] y[3,1]-x[1,2] x[4,3] y[2,4] y[3,1]
+x[2,3] x[4,1] y[1,4] y[3,2]-x[2,1] x[4,3] y[1,4] y[3,2]
-x[2,3] x[4,1] y[1,2] y[3,4]+x[2,1] x[4,3] y[1,2] y[3,4]
-x[1,3] x[4,2] y[2,1] y[3,4]+x[1,2] x[4,3] y[2,1] y[3,4]
+x[1,4] x[3,2] y[2,3] y[4,1]-x[1,2] x[3,4] y[2,3] y[4,1]
+x[1,4] x[2,3] y[3,2] y[4,1]-x[1,3] x[2,4] y[3,2] y[4,1]
+x[2,4] x[3,1] y[1,3] y[4,2]-x[2,1] x[3,4] y[1,3] y[4,2]
-x[1,4] x[2,3] y[3,1] y[4,2]+x[1,3] x[2,4] y[3,1] y[4,2]
-x[2,4] x[3,1] y[1,2] y[4,3]+x[2,1] x[3,4] y[1,2] y[4,3]
-x[1,4] x[3,2] y[2,1] y[4,3]+x[1,2] x[3,4] y[2,1] y[4,3]
```

how to represent it in the form

```
 (x[3,2] x[4,1]-x[3,1] x[4,2]) (y[1,4] y[2,3]-y[1,3] y[2,4])
+(x[2,3] x[4,1]-x[2,1] x[4,3]) (y[1,4] y[3,2]-y[1,2] y[3,4])
+(x[1,3] x[4,2]-x[1,2] x[4,3]) (y[2,4] y[3,1]-y[2,1] y[3,4])
+(x[1,4] x[2,3]-x[1,3] x[2,4]) (y[3,2] y[4,1]-y[3,1] y[4,2])
+(x[2,4] x[3,1]-x[2,1] x[3,4]) (y[1,3] y[4,2]-y[1,2] y[4,3])
+(x[1,4] x[3,2]-x[1,2] x[3,4]) (y[2,3] y[4,1]-y[2,1] y[4,3])
```

At the request in a comment, here is another kind of example: represent

```
 a^2 b^2+a^2 c^2+b^2 c^2+a^2 d^2+b^2 d^2+c^2 d^2+6 a b c d
-a^2 b c-a b^2 c-a b c^2-a^2 b d-a b^2 d-a^2 c d
-b^2 c d-a c^2 d-b c^2 d-a b d^2-a c d^2-b c d^2
```

in the form

```
(((a-b)(c-d))^2+((a-c)(b-d))^2+((a-d)(b-c))^2)/2
```

Note that for this case one might try `SymmetricReduction`, which gives *not* what I want, namely

```
(a b+a c+a d+b c+b d+a d)^2-3(a+b+c+d)(a b c+a b d+a c d+b c d)+12a b c d
```

Comment: The best I can do is `Simplify[expr, ComplexityFunction -> (Count[#, 1|2|3|4, Infinity] &)]]`

Comment: Depending on the actual expression you'd like to reformat, it may be better to attempt to *verify* correctness rather than automatically do simplification.  For instance, `Simplify[expr==expr2]` yields True.  Your initial `expr` is clearly some sum of products of x's and y's indexed by permutations, if we had smaller/larger examples perhaps we could figure out exactly how `expr`'s are generated in order to form verifiable `expr2`'s.